# @Validated @Size LongArray controller with kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to validate the existence, and size (min, max) of a request parameter.

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
@Validated
class TaskController(val taskService: TaskService) {
  @GetMapping("/byIds")
  suspend fun getByIds(@Size(min = 1, max = 20) ids: LongArray): Map<Long, Task> {
    return taskService.getByIds(ids.toSet())
      .toList()
      .associateBy { it.id!! }
  }
}
```

The test I am using:

```
@Test
fun `getByIds handles ids-parameter out of bounds`() {
  val tooManyIds = (1L..21)
  client
    .get()
    .uri { uriBuilder ->
      uriBuilder
        .path("/tasks/byIds")
        .queryParam("ids", tooManyIds.joinToString(","))
        .build()
    }
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus().is4xxClientError
}
```

This fails with this exception:

```
2021-04-19 12:21:39.077 ERROR 31174 --- [-1 @coroutine#1] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [2c1f6279]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/tasks/byIds"

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:4164) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
```

So first thing I thought was, that maybe kotlins null-safety is a problem here.
I know about using `@NotNull`, because `@Size(...)` is fine for null values, so I tried making the ids nullable but adding `@NotNull`:

```kotlin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
@Validated
class TaskController(val taskService: TaskService) {
  @GetMapping("/byIds")
  suspend fun getByIds(@NotNull @Size(min = 1, max = 20) ids: LongArray?): Map<Long, Task> {
    return taskService.getByIds(ids!!.toSet())
      .toList()
      .associateBy { it.id!! }
  }
}
```

This fails with the same error.

How should I apply the validation framework properly?

---

**UPDATE**

Full stack trace when hitting the endpoint in the running application (not a test) - it is the same error. Note that the same error shows up independent of the actual request and whether it fulfills the validation or not:

```
2021-04-28 23:51:30.919 ERROR 19820 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [edc8765e-3] 500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/tasks/byIds?ids=1"

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:4164) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.example.tasks.TaskController#getByIds(long[], Continuation) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ com.example.core.ReactorContextLocaleWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.logout.LogoutWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/tasks/byIds?ids=1" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:4164) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.properties.javabean.JavaBeanExecutable.getParameterName(JavaBeanExecutable.java:86) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ParameterMetaData$Builder.build(ParameterMetaData.java:165) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ExecutableMetaData$Builder.findParameterMetaData(ExecutableMetaData.java:436) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.ExecutableMetaData$Builder.build(ExecutableMetaData.java:391) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.BeanMetaDataBuilder$BuilderDelegate.build(BeanMetaDataBuilder.java:260) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.aggregated.BeanMetaDataBuilder.build(BeanMetaDataBuilder.java:133) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManagerImpl.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManagerImpl.java:206) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManagerImpl.getBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManagerImpl.java:165) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:267) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:235) ~[hibernate-validator-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor.invoke(MethodValidationInterceptor.java:110) ~[spring-context-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at com.example.tasks.TaskController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e6ef38.getByIds(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0-RC.jar:1.5.0-RC-release-664 (1.5.0-RC)]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Instance.call(CallerImpl.kt:113) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0-RC.jar:1.5.0-RC-release-664 (1.5.0-RC)]
        at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:108) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0-RC.jar:1.5.0-RC-release-664 (1.5.0-RC)]
        at kotlin.reflect.full.KCallables.callSuspend(KCallables.kt:55) ~[kotlin-reflect-1.5.0-RC.jar:1.5.0-RC-release-664 (1.5.0-RC)]
        at org.springframework.core.CoroutinesUtils$invokeSuspendingFunction$mono$1.invokeSuspend(CoroutinesUtils.kt:64) ~[spring-core-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) ~[kotlin-stdlib-1.5.0-RC.jar:1.5.0-RC-release-664 (1.5.0-RC)]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:349) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.3.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.3.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:27) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.3.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.3.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.4.3.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.MonoKt$monoInternal$1.accept(Mono.kt:55) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactor-1.4.3.jar:na]
        at kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.MonoKt$monoInternal$1.accept(Mono.kt) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactor-1.4.3.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:57) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:284) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:325) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:236) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:181) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:255) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:169) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2193) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2067) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:448) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:218) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:148) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:281) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:860) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:488) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:421) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:270) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:448) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:218) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:255) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:940) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:84) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2399) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2193) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2067) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:81) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:846) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:608) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:588) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:465) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:277) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:178) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1815) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:269) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:199) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.4.5.jar:3.4.5]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

2021-04-28 23:51:30.922  INFO 19820 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.netty.http.server.AccessLog      : 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0:60712 - - [28/Apr/2021:23:51:30 +0200] "GET /tasks/byIds?ids=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 0 24 ms
```

Removing the `@Validated` annotation removes the error (but of course no validation takes place then..)

### UPDATE 2

Turns out it is a bug

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23499
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23152
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22462

There is no fix available and the issue is blocked :-(