# failed to validate request params in a Spring Boot/Kotlin Coroutines controller

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, hibernate-validator

In a SpringBoot/Kotlin Coroutines project, I have a controller class like this.

```kotlin
@RestContollser
@Validated
class PostController(private val posts: PostRepository) {

    suspend fun search(@RequestParam q:String, @RequestParam  @Min(0) offset:Int, @RequestParam  @Min(1) limit:Int): ResponseEntity<Any> {}

}
```

The validation on the `@ResquestBody` works as the general Spring WebFlux, but when testing

*validating request params* , it failed and throws an exception like:

```sh
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:4165)
    Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below:
```

It is not a `ConstraintViolationException`.

Comment: Seems to be a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67160337/validated-size-longarray-controller-with-kotlin

Comment: Can you post your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the happy songs' comments, I found the best solution by now to overcome this barrier from the [Spring Github issues#23499](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23499).

As explained in comments of this issue and PaulNuk's answer, there is a `Continuation` will be appended to the method arguments at runtime, which will fail the index computation of the method parameter names in the Hibernate Validator.

The solution is changing the `ParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(Method)` method and adding a empty string as the additional parameter name when it is a **suspend** function.

```kotlin
class KotlinCoroutinesLocalValidatorFactoryBean : LocalValidatorFactoryBean() {
    override fun getClockProvider(): ClockProvider = DefaultClockProvider.INSTANCE

    override fun postProcessConfiguration(configuration: javax.validation.Configuration<*>) {
        super.postProcessConfiguration(configuration)

        val discoverer = PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer()
        discoverer.addDiscoverer(SuspendAwareKotlinParameterNameDiscoverer())
        discoverer.addDiscoverer(StandardReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer())
        discoverer.addDiscoverer(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer())

        val defaultProvider = configuration.defaultParameterNameProvider
        configuration.parameterNameProvider(object : ParameterNameProvider {
            override fun getParameterNames(constructor: Constructor<*>): List<String> {
                val paramNames: Array<String>? = discoverer.getParameterNames(constructor)
                return paramNames?.toList() ?: defaultProvider.getParameterNames(constructor)
            }

            override fun getParameterNames(method: Method): List<String> {
                val paramNames: Array<String>? = discoverer.getParameterNames(method)
                return paramNames?.toList() ?: defaultProvider.getParameterNames(method)
            }
        })
    }
}

class SuspendAwareKotlinParameterNameDiscoverer : ParameterNameDiscoverer {

    private val defaultProvider = KotlinReflectionParameterNameDiscoverer()

    override fun getParameterNames(constructor: Constructor<*>): Array<String>? =
        defaultProvider.getParameterNames(constructor)

    override fun getParameterNames(method: Method): Array<String>? {
        val defaultNames = defaultProvider.getParameterNames(method) ?: return null
        val function = method.kotlinFunction
        return if (function != null && function.isSuspend) {
            defaultNames + ""
        } else defaultNames
    }
}
```

Then declare a new validator factory bean.

```kotlin
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    fun defaultValidator(): LocalValidatorFactoryBean {
        val factoryBean = KotlinCoroutinesLocalValidatorFactoryBean()
        factoryBean.messageInterpolator = MessageInterpolatorFactory().getObject()
        return factoryBean
    }
```

Get the [complete sample codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-puzzles/blob/master/validation-ktco) from my Github.

**Update**: Spring 6 has built-in Validation Support for Kotlin Coroutines Controller.

Comment: Hey Hantsy, I tried out the sample you provided. I'm getting a conflicting bean error with this step. `"org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.validation.Validator' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: defaultValidator,webFluxValidator"`

Not able to figure out where the webFluxValidator is coming from

Comment: I think your codes lacked the `@Primary` annotations.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a bug in the framework when you are using coroutines (update , it is, I saw Happy Songs comment). In summary:

"@Validated is indeed not yet Coroutines compliant, we need to fix that by using Coroutines aware methods to discover method parameters."

The trouble is that the signature of the method on your controller is actually enhanced by Spring to have an extra parameter, like this, adding a continuation:

```
public java.lang.Object com.example.react.PostController.search(java.lang.String,int,int,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)
```

so when the hibernate validator calls getParameter names to get the list of parameters on your method, it thinks there are 4 in total on the request, and then gets an index out of bounds exception trying to get the 4th (index 3).

If you put a breakpoint on the return of this:

```
   @Override
        public E get(int index) {
            return a[index];
        }
```

and put a breakpoint condition of `index ==3 && a.length <4` you can see what is going on.

I'd report it as a bug on the Spring issue tracker.

You might be better off taking an alternative approach, as described here, using a RequestBody as a DTO and using the @Valid annotation

https://www.vinsguru.com/spring-webflux-validation/

Comment: Bean validation should work at method params of any components as Jakarta EE environment, unfortunately Spring handle the request body an request params  differently.